# Building a title block for a class

Tags: macros, titles, titling

I am trying to build a class with a title block (using titling) such that the end user enters data into two fields. One variable is sopchaptertitle, and the other is sopchapternumber. I want to then concatenate them, and place the resulting title some distance from the top of the page and centered on the page. This will be followed by some distance of white space and the first section.

It should look something like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sop}

% Passes and class options to the underlying article class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

% Redefine the page margins
\RequirePackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=.75in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}

% Modifications to the section titles
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% Title block
\RequirePackage{titling}
\newcommand{\sopchaptertitle}[1]{\newcommand{\thesopchaptertitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sopchapternumber}[1]{\newcommand{\thesopchapternumber}{#1}}
\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythetitle}{#1}}
\let\oldpretitle\pretitle
\renewcommand{\pretitle}[1]{\oldpretitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythepretitle}{#1}}
\let\oldposttitle\posttitle
\renewcommand{\posttitle}[1]{\oldposttitle{#1}\newcommand{\mytheposttitle}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\mythepretitle{\setlength{\droptitle}{12.0cm}\begin{center}\LARGE}
\mythetitle{\thesopchaptertitle\ \thesopchapternumber}
\mytheposttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
}
%.... a page N of M section (which works)
% For easier customization of itemized, enumerated, and other lists
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% For hyperlinked cross-references
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
% Ensure first page is correct style
\thispagestyle{plain}
% That's all, folks!
\endinput
```

It is being fed this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sop}
%
% SOP Standard Form Data
\sopchaptertitle{This is my procedure title}
\sopchapternumber{this is my procedure number D.4}
%...more of the above
%Here begins the actual document
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Main Title}

\section{Approval}
Approval1....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}\\\vspace{1.5in}
Approval2....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}

\newpage

\section{Purpose and Discussion}
%...more of the above...
\end{document}
```

And I am getting these errors:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   M
l.4 \sopchaptertitle
                    {this is my procedure title}
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   M
l.4 \sopchaptertitle
                    {this is my procedure title}
?
```

And

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./sop-test.out)
(./sop-test.out)
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyOrg@maketitle ->\mythepretitle 
                                  {\setlength {\droptitle }{12.0cm}\begin {c...
l.15 

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\HyOrg@maketitle ...12.0cm}\begin {center}\LARGE }
                                                   \mythetitle     {\thesopchapt...
    l.15 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyOrg@maketitle ... {center}\LARGE } \mythetitle 
                                                  {\thesopchaptertitle \ \th...
l.15 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyOrg@maketitle ...apternumber } \mytheposttitle 
                                                  {\par \end {center}\vskip ...
l.15 

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.15 

?
```

The braces seem balanced, and everything but the `droptitle` seems to work.

Could someone please explain why `droptitle` is not functioning?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It's hard to tell without a complete example; there's `hyperref` involved but your code doesn't load it.

Comment: @egreg - I am not using any links in this. How does hyperref play a role? It is being loaded, however.

Comment: I don't know; but the problem is certainly related to `hyperref`, as it's the package that uses the prefix `HyOrg` for commands it redefines.

Comment: @egreg Probably comes from the `titling` package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Yes, indeed. But the interaction with hyperref seems to have a role.

Comment: Well, the macro `\mythepretitle` is never defined, so how can LaTeX know it? It's defined by `\pretitle`, which is never called.

Comment: @egreg The cls is loading hyperref on line 37!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Now I can see it and spot the real origin of the problem. The class wants to use `\mythepretitle` without ever giving a value to it.

Comment: @egreg It is actually very buggy. Better to just re-create what is needed from scratch, if the OP posts an image.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides tried to attach an image, but I don't have the 10 reputation points required to do so.

Comment: @matt You got them now:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `\mythepretitle` is called without ever being given a definition.

According to the code in `sop.cls`, you have

```
\let\oldpretitle\pretitle
\renewcommand{\pretitle}[1]{\oldpretitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythepretitle}{#1}}
```

but you never do

```
\pretitle{something}
```

so `\mythepretitle` is never defined, although you want to use it in `\maketitle`.

It's not clear why you want an exact duplicate of `\pretitle`. In `titling.sty` we find

```
\newcommand{\pretitle}[1]{\def\@bspretitle{#1}}
```

so when used in `\maketitle` it will use the argument at the right spot, see the definition of `\maketitle`. But you're redefining `\maketitle` yourself, so the loading of `titling` becomes completely useless and using `\pretitle` instead of `\mythepretitle` will do nothing.

---

Using the features provided by `titling` you can achieve your result more easily:

#### `sop.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sop}

% Passes and class options to the underlying article class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

% Redefine the page margins
\RequirePackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=.75in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}

% Modifications to the section titles
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% Title block
\RequirePackage{titling}
\newcommand{\sopchaptertitle}[1]{\def\@sopchaptertitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\sopchapternumber}[1]{\def\@sopchapternumber{#1}}

%%% Drop before title
\setlength\droptitle{12cm}

%%% Define the internal variable \@title to be the supplied data
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
  \def\@title{\@sopchaptertitle\ \@sopchapternumber}}

%%% No author field, so \maketitlehookb gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb[1]{}

%%% No date field, so \maketitlehookc gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc[1]{}

%%% Formatting the title
\pretitle{\centering\sffamily\LARGE}

%%% Space after the title
\posttitle{\par\vspace{3cm}}

%%% The rest of the class    

%.... a page N of M section (which works)
% For easier customization of itemized, enumerated, and other lists
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% For hyperlinked cross-references
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
% Ensure first page is correct style
\thispagestyle{plain}
% That's all, folks!
\endinput
```

If we use this with your minimal example, we get the following result

[image]

Probably the drop should be adjusted, taking into account the top margin, the head height and the head separation. If you want exactly 12cm from the top paper margin, possibly

```
 \setlength{\droptitle}{\dimexpr 12cm-0.75in-\headheight-\headsep\relax}
```

is what you need.

Comment: The structure of everything is starting to make more sense. I'm still not there, but this helped.

Comment: @Matt I updated the answer based on the additional information you gave